# Github Codespaces Laravel 10 serve css

Tags: php, laravel, github, codespaces, github-codespaces

I am coding using `Laravel Framework 10.1.5` with github codespaces.

I am starting the server with `php artisan serve` and when I want to load a `css-file` in my blade view I am using        `<link href="{{ asset('fonts/google-font/css.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`.

However, this link is resolved to: `<link href="http://localhost/fonts/google-font/css.css" rel="stylesheet">`

My codespace url looks like that: `https://githubUser-legendary-goggles-vp4432qvj12xsas32y234-8000.preview.app.github.dev/`

Hence, my css file does not load.

I using a `devcontainer` and here is my configuration:

```
// See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/devcontainer.json for format details.
{
    "name": "codespaces-laravel",
    "dockerComposeFile": ["docker-compose.yml"],
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "service": "app",
    "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
    "extensions": [
        "editorconfig.editorconfig",
        "ryannaddy.laravel-artisan",
        "amiralizadeh9480.laravel-extra-intellisense",
        "stef-k.laravel-goto-controller",
        "codingyu.laravel-goto-view",
        "mikestead.dotenv",
        "eg2.tslint",
        "christian-kohler.path-intellisense",
        "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "#terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    "forwardPorts": [80],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    "postCreateCommand": "cp .env.example .env && composer install && php artisan key:generate && yarn install && yarn run development",
    "portsAttributes": {
        "80": {
            "label": "HTTP"
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion how to

Comment: Have you tried to change the APP_URL on your `.env` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asset helper prepends your `ASSET_URL`, defined in the .env file.

You can update your `ASSET_URL` to point to your website URL `https://githubUser-legendary-goggles-vp4432qvj12xsas32y234-8000.preview.app.github.dev/` in your .env file.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-asset